# Overwriting Existing String with a new enterd Vakue in Textbox-Android

Tags: android

Here Activity A ="ActivityLoaderActivity"; &&
Activity B      ="ExplicitlyLoadedActivity"

I have Two Activities....Activity A(contains two buttons and a string with text "NoText Entered") and Activity B.

In Activity B ,I have a text Box in which if I enter any String and press enter,it should come back to  Activity A and on Activity A the string with "No Text Enterd" should be replaced with the text which we have entered in Activity B.

The Navigation is not the problem.The Issue i am facing here is I am unable to overwrite the String.

Activity B :

```
private void enterClicked() {
        Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");    
        // TODO - Save user provided input from the EditText field 
        String str = mEditText.getText().toString();
        // TODO - Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this,ActivityLoaderActivity.class);   
        mIntent.putExtra("str",str);        
        // TODO - Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
        setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);      
        // TODO - Finish the Activity
        finish();
}
```

And Activity A code is :

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
    // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
    // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {

        /*String extraData=data.getStringExtra("str");*/
        Intent i = getIntent();
        mUserTextView.setText(i.getStringExtra("str"));

    }   

}
```

Pls let me know the way of overwriting since Navigation is working for me perfectly fine

Comment: Does anything show up in your logcat?

Comment: How do you start activity B from A?

Comment: @ Nagy Vilmos :  As soon I launch this on the emulator,Screen one corresponding to activity A is launched.... and on click of one button,it directs to screen correponding to activity B....

Comment: On the logcat,
It is entering the Entered onActivityResult() of Class B but not the but not onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  of Class A......has it got to do with result code and request code passing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (requestCode == GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String userInputFromExplicit = data.getStringExtra("str");
                mUserTextView.setText(userInputFromExplicit);
            }
        }
```